# import vue 3 component into a JS file with props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a JS file that holds a function and I want to import a vue component with respective props into that function.

I've imported the component like this:

```
import Component from './component.vue'
```

The vue component is imported successfully if I just do this:

```
function myFunction(){
  return Component
}
```

But not if I try to enter a value for a prop like this:

```
function myFunction(){
  return Component('propvalue')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Component props are actualized during rendering, so return a wrapper functional component with needed props:

```
import {h} from 'vue';
function myFunction(){
  return () => h(Component, {prop: 'propvalue'});
}
```